# "Showroom" Installation of Ubuntu?

Tags: installation, re-installation

I'm selling my old netbook with a clean version of Ubuntu 10.10 (the last version I was using on it) installed. Is it possible to install Ubuntu in such a way that the new buyer can choose his own username, password, computer name, etc., or must I do that myself?

I'm not sure if there's a technical term for this sort of installation, but I'm referring to it as a "showroom" installation, as it's how the OS might behave if you were buying it new off the showroom floor.

Comment: It is called oem installation .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The normal boot cd has an option for this. Just download the  normal iso [from here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download) and boot from it and then press any key and select OEM install .